# SpringBootTest mock Authentication Principal with a custom User does not work

Tags: java, authentication, spring-boot, mockito

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.2 and I am new with Spring Boot. 
I have an Authentication Filter to set the current user information when the user log in. 
In an advice for the controller, I made the call to get the current userId as below:

```
public static String getCurrentUserToken(){
    return ((AuthenticatedUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUserId();
}
```

Here is my custom AuthenticatedUser:

```
public class AuthenticatedUser implements Serializable {

private final String userName;
private final String userId;
private final String sessionId;

public AuthenticatedUser(String userName, String userId, String sessionId) {
    super();
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.sessionId = sessionId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public String getSessionId() {
    return sessionId;
}
```

}

Everything works fine. 
However, the filter does not work in integration testing and I need to mock a current user. 
I searched a lot on how to mock a user but none of them help me. I finally found out this guide  which is likely close to what I wanted: https://aggarwalarpit.wordpress.com/2017/05/17/mocking-spring-security-context-for-unit-testing/ 
Below is my testing class following that guideline:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class PersonalLoanPreApprovalTest {

@Before
public void initDB() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testRequestPersonalLoanPreApproval_Me() {
  AuthenticatedUser applicationUser = new 
  AuthenticatedUser("test@abc.com", "2d1b5ae3", "123");
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new ApiKeyAuthentication(applicationUser);
  SecurityContext securityContext = mock(SecurityContext.class);

  when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
  SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);

  // error at this line
  when(securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()) .thenReturn(applicationUser); 

  // The controller for this api has the advice to get the userId
  MyResponse response = restTemplate.getForObject(url.toString(), MyResponse.class);
}
}
```

I got this error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
AuthenticatedUser cannot be returned by getAuthentication()
getAuthentication() should return Authentication
```

I spent couple days on this already, tried a lot of suggestions I found but still failed. I also tried to remove the line that cause error, but when the error gone, I still could not get the current user information in my controller advice.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE1:** Just wanted to have my results with some modification in the code.

With @glitch suggestion, I changed the code to mock the authentication and user in my test method as below:

```
 @Test
 public void testRequestPersonalLoanPreApproval_Me() {
    AuthenticatedUser applicationUser = new AuthenticatedUser("testtu_free@cs.com", "2d1b5ae3-cf04-44f5-9493-f0518cab4554", "123");
    Authentication authentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
    SecurityContext securityContext = Mockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);
    Mockito.when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
    Mockito.when(authentication.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(applicationUser);      

  // The controller for this api has the advice to get the userId
  MyResponse response = restTemplate.getForObject(url.toString(), MyResponse.class);
}
}
```

I now can get rid of the error in the testing class. I debugged into the code, see that the securityContext has value when I am in the testing class. But when I jump to the code inside the controller advice, the below get returns null:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

Comment: try:
`when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn((Authentication)authentication);`

Comment: Thanks @mangotang for your suggestion. I tried it and still have the old error at the line: `when(securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).thenReturn(applicationUser);`. Do you have any other suggestion for me?

Answer (score 11):

There a Spring test annotation (`org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser`) which does this for you...

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "myUser", roles = { "myAuthority" })
public void aTest(){
    // any usage of `Authentication` in this test invocation will get an instance with the user name "myUser" and a granted authority "myAuthority"
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can continue with your current approach by mocking Spring's `Authentication`. For example, in your test case:

```
Authentication authentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
```

Then tell Spring's `SecurityContextHolder` to store this `Authentication` instance:

```
SecurityContext securityContext = Mockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);
Mockito.when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(auth);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
```

Now, if your code needs `Authentication` to return something (the user name perhaps) you just set some expectations on the mocked `Authentication` instance in the usual way e.g.

```
Mockito.when(authentication.getName()).thenReturn("aName");
```

This is quite close to what you are already doing but you have just mocked the wrong type.

**Update 1:** in response to this update to the OP:

> I now can get rid of the error in the testing class. I debugged into the code, see that the securityContext has value when I am in the testing class. But when I jump to the code inside the controller advice, the below get returns null:
>
> `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`

You just need to set an expectation on the mocked `Authentication`, for example:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken principal = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("aUserName", "aPassword");
Mockito.when(authentication.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(principal);
```

With the above code this line ...

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

... will return that `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.

Since you use a custom type (`ApiKeyAuthentication`, I think?) you should just let `authentication.getPrincipal()` return that type instead of a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.

Comment: Thanks @glitch for your suggestion. My difficulty is that I have custom Authentication, which is `ApiKeyAuthentication`. Inside that custom authentication, I have a custom user `AuthenticatedUser`. And to add more complicated stuffs, the information I want to get back is the `userId` inside `AuthenticatedUser`. The information I need to get was posted in the very first code section in my original post. I am the one who continue the work and all the custom authentication stuffs were created before. I appreciated if you can have any other suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to glytching's answer I had to add the following line when mocking:

```
SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_GLOBAL);
```

That is because the spring boot test code doesn't run in the same thread as the spring boot application you're testing, and the default strategy is ThreadLocal. With MODE_GLOBAL you ensure that the mocked SecurityContext object is actually returned in your application.

Comment: This is a time saver answer, I was having issues by getting authentication as null when using `@WithUserDetails("admin")` in my controller, but then I only added the line you said and it started applying globally, there is no need to mock explicitly authentication and security context, thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. Furthermore, `setStrategyName` must be set before setting `setContext` on SecurityContextHolder, or it does not work (or at least it was like this in my case).